# When is the real part of this complex number positive?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z$ be a complex number, set $w =z+1/z-1$

For what values of $z$ is the real part of $w$ positive?

I have tried working with the formula $2\Re(w) = z + \bar z$ but have not been able to get anywhere. Can someone help?

Comment: Let $z=x+y\mathrm{i}$.

Comment: `I have tried working with the formula ...` The formula you posted is wrong. That should be $2 \Re(w) = w + \bar w$ instead. Try working with that one.

Comment: Is it $\;\frac{z+1}{z-1}\;,\;\;or\;\;z+\frac1z-1\;,\;\;or\;\;z+\frac1{z-1}\ldots...??$ Use some parentheses!

Comment: @DonAntonio it is (z+1)/(z-1) $

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $z=a+bi$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. Then $w=a+bi+1/(a+bi)-1=a+bi+(a-bi)/|z|^2-1.$